# Fix Nestjs Swagger docs not showing on Nginx server

Tags: nginx, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nginx-reverse-proxy

I had issue with my swagger docs not displaying which i searched for solution and could not find it. i was able to solve that and i am sharing for all to benefit.

### Problem

[image]

### Solution

adding this block of configuration on your website config fixes the problem.
[image]

Comment: Is this a genric solution or just for your case ?

Comment: should work for nginx server if you app is running on port 8000

Comment: I tried to update my port on 5000 and it's still not working